# Cómo traducir "wrapped text"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

En un documento HTML un párrafo de texto muy largo cambia de linea para ajustarse a las dimensiones de la caja padre. En inglés esto se llama `wrapped text`. ¿Cómo podemos traducir `wrapped text` en español?

Comment: En español se suele hablar del "ajuste de línea" para saber si una línea de texto debe ajustarse a los márgenes o no, pero no sé si eso es exactamente lo que buscas.

Comment: @Charlie Muchísimas gracias: `ajuste de línea` me parece perfecto. "En SVG el texto _doesn't wrap_". Creo que voy a utilizar ajustar y `ajuste de línea`. Me encantaría aceptar su respuesta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En español se suele usar "ajuste de línea" para saber si una línea de texto debe ajustarse a los márgenes o no. Aquí tienes un ejemplo del menú del Notepad++ donde se usa:

[image: Notepad++]

Y también en el Bloc de notas del Windows:

[image: Bloc de notas]

En todo caso, creo que estas opciones de menú en inglés son "line wrap", que no es exactamente la expresión que buscas traducir. En la web del IATE (que traduce terminología específica para textos de la Unión Europea) se sugiere que la traducción de "text wrapping" debería ser "ajuste del texto".

Comment: I think in English line wrapping just puts as many characters as possible on the line, word wrap adds the feature that  it never splits words for some meaning of word, justification alters the spacing so that the text runs flush with both margins.

Comment: Do Html tags have a Spanish version? I ask because for example the "<td>" tag inside the "<table>" tag has the "nowrap" attribute that forces the cell data to stay on one line.

Comment: “Wrapped text” specifies the text, but “ajuste de línea” specifies the action., right? How would you say, “I want wrapped text, not continuous text.” “Quiero líneas ajustadas, no contínuas?”

Comment: @Arrendajo "Quiero que las líneas [de texto] se ajusten [al ancho de la ventana]"

Answer (score 3):

When I was on a brief work assignment in Spain we said, “la acomodación de texto” or “ajuste del texto.” In Buenos Aires we used the English “Word Wrap”, pronounced with a heavy Porteño accent. In the rest of Lat Am we used “ajuste (automático) de línea.” I checked the Microsoft Word technical support page in Spanish; however, it did not specifically address your question. Cheers.